# HTMLElement.toString() only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, tostring

I have found an error in FireFox and Opera.(I'm running Debian Whezee, Firefox 9.0.1, Opera 11.60, Chrome 16.0.912.63)
When you type something like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.toString = function(){ return "Hello" }
alert(a+" World");
```

In Chrome you will get alert box with "Hello World" as you expect, but in firefox and opera (don't know about IE) you get something like this "[object HTMLElement] World"

What I've tried to solve this:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Hello" };
Function.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Hello" };
```

It doesn't work Because DOM elements are not Object (don't inherits from Object and therefor Function) and even this didn't help:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Hello" };
Element.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Hello" };
Node.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Hello" };
```

Because HTMLElement, Element, Node are all interfaces and not functions.

Now my question is where to report this mistake? Can someone help me with this?

**//Edit**

This is my original toString function:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.toString = function(){
    var tmp=document.createElement('div');
    tmp.appendChild(this);
    return tmp.innerHTML;
}
```

As you can see this is alternative to outerHTML and I need this as a default behavior in following line

```
document.getElemntById('someID').innerHTML += "click this link:"+a;
```

The result should be like this:

```
<div id='someID'>click this link:<a></a></div>
```

Comment: Who says it is a mistake? Apparently, Firefox and Opera don't allow overriding `toString` of DOM nodes. As they are host objects, they are not subject to the ECMAScript specification, so it's perfectly fine.

Comment: So maybe someone knows what can I do to get similar effect. Is there any other method to override that would do the trick. Because using a.toString() every time is not that obvious when I'm using Chrome and others use Firefox or Opera. I usually say "Strange, My works fine", and then silently adding .toString() where needed.

Comment: The question is, what exactly do you want your `toString` function to do? If you really only want to get the inner text, you should use `innerText` or `textContent`. That's the standard way.

Comment: @fon60 Why not just `alert( a.innerHTML + ' World' );`?

Comment: I remembered my self one thing. this method is defined in object but is not called by the engine/javascript as default. So when I do alert(a.toString()+" World"); work fine everywhere. What interest me is that. Array object has toString that can be overwritten but why DOM elements don't have this. Please let Node inherits from Object. Please.

Comment: @fon60: The DOM implementation is not written in JavaScript (I assume). Browsers only provide an *interface* for the DOM to JavaScript. `Array` is a built-in object in JavaScript and has to follow the specification. The DOM interface does not have to. That's how it is. Why don't you create a `outerHTML` function and write  `"click this link:" + outerHTML(a);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any place to report this since calling `toString` on dom elements is not standard behavior.  To get the html content from an element you're supposed to use innerHTML, and to get just the text content, `textContent` (or innerText for older IE browsers)

Comment: my .toString function is more like:

Comment: Sorry, I've started answering, but decided to edit original question and forgot to delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you are trying to change the default/native behavior for your project; it's almost always a **bad** idea. I guess I might suggest:

```
var aa = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(aa);
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('*');
for (var i = 0, len = nodeList.length; i < len; i ++) {
    nodeList[i].myCustomFunction = toStringOverride;
}
function toStringOverride() {
    return "Hello ";
}

alert(aa.myCustomFunction() + " World");
```

Comment: A case where this might be useful is if you have a bunch of functions which expect a certain parameter to be a string, but you have a new requirement that they could also be an HTML UI element (in which case you want to use the value of the element).  Now you have to explicitly add a check/convert to every function whereas if they are already converting to string, you just have to override `toString` in each element you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

> Array object has toString that can be overwritten, but why DOM elements don't have this

An `Array` is a native JavaScript object. The ECMAScript standard lays down the requirements of how JS objects work, including the ability to hack a different `toString` into the prototype.

However the DOM objects are not specified anywhere to be native-JS objects or to adhere to the general rules of behaviour for JS objects. They are permitted to be what the standard calls ‘host objects’, which are much less well-specified.

Hacking their prototypes is very unreliable and not at all a good idea. One JS library, prototype.js, tried, and the results were [messy](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

> Please let Node inherits from Object. Please

Sorry, Stack Overflow has no authority to require `Node` to be a native JavaScript object!

Until you can persuade all the browser vendors to standardise on native JS objects for the DOM, you will have to use an external `function Node_getOuterHTML(node) { ... }` and call it explicitly, `"click this link:"+Node_getOuterHTML(a)`.

Although, it would generally be better to append the node you created to the document directly rather than send it through the DOM->HTML-markup->DOM serialise-and-parse cycle it's undergoing at the moment with `innerHTML`.

Comment: Your chances of standardizing on "native" (or more precisely "non-proxy") JS objects for the DOM are precisely 0, because web compat requires behaviors from the DOM that native objects simply can't have per spec.  A lot of things in the DOM can be native objects, but a lot of others just can't.